# Why does the plot of volume and temperature have a kink in a second order phase transition?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase

[image]

The $(b)$ part of the figure shows how thermodynamic variables change in a second order phase transformation.
We observe there is a kink in the plot of volume with temperature.

Why is that so?

The plot is from http://faculty.chem.queensu.ca/people/faculty/mombourquette/Chem221/5_PhaseChanges/PhaseThermo.asp

Comment: Because they are second order phase transitions? GO back to the definition of a second order phase transition, such as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition.

Comment: Thank you Mr Jon Custer. I was interested in the actual mechanism as to why the kink was there.

Comment: An example for a), first order of phase transition, is the one about liquid water $\ce{->}$ gaseous water / steam; you have both a sudden jump in $\Delta{}V/\Delta{}T$ and the energy needed for this transition ends in latent heat.  Guess what, not all transitions involve latent heat (i.e., compare with your lecture notes, references at disposition, etc.).

Comment: Thank you buttonworth. I was interested in the second order transition in which there isn't a jump but just a bend in the plot of V with T

Comment: @YasirSadiq - because instead of a jump in volume, there is a jump in the derivative of volume (for example). And for a third order phase transition there would be a jump in the second derivative of volume... That is how the order of a phase transition is defined.